# Expand/Shrink columns based on cell value through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to add columns automatically based on a cell value in another sheet. 
For example, if the cell value says 25, I'd like it to expand the columns (including formulas/format) to insert 3 more columns after 22.

If the cell value changes to 20, I'd like it to remove the last two columns.

Is there a way to do this in VBA? I figure there may need to be some type of refresh button, unless there's another way to make it a change event?

Thanks in advance!

[Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoNSB.png)

```
Sub AddCols()

Dim lastColumn As Long

lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'lastColumn.Select

Cells(5, lastColumn + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

EDIT: I've tried the following code below, but it is constantly giving me an error when the change event occurs.

```
colCount = Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(1).End(xlToRight).Column
checkCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

If checkCell > colCount Then
    cellDiff = checkCell - colCount
    Range(Columns(colCount + 1), Columns(colCount + cellDiff)).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range(Cells(1, ColCount), Cells(lRow, ColCount)).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(1, ColCount), Cells(lRow, ColCount + cellDiff)), Type:=xlFillDefault
Else
    cellDiff = colCount - checkCell
    startCol = colCount - cellDiff + 1
    Range(Columns(startCol), Columns(colCount)).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End If
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this in VBA; in fact, there are numerous ways to do this in VBA.  What have you tried thusfar?

Comment: @Cyril Great to hear! I'm really at a loss for what to try, but any suggestions would be great. I'm having trouble with having the cells add/subtract based on the cell value. I can hard code the cells but I'm unable to have it read the variable and adapt accordingly

Comment: Share the Code that you've tried so we can work on helping to correct where you're currently at.  This will be a better approach, considering "how do i do this" would be highly opinionated and too broad for this forum.

Comment: @Cyril just added it!

Comment: In reviewing the provided code, you appear to have not attempted to handle much.  You find the last column and paste, though we don't see what is copied.  Might I suggest taking some time with the macro recorder to get more info about what is to be copied, etc?  Additionally, take a stab at using either an If-statement or a Select Case statement, which should allow you to assess conditions to prompt an action.

Comment: @Cyril I can express what I'd like in pseudocode pretty easily, but it's just a matter of converting it into VBA.

Comment: *colCount = Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(1).End(xlToRight).Column* should go from a cell reference, not a whole row.  Where are you getting errors in your updated code, and what are the errors?

Comment: @Cyril It's acting very funky, like inputting random values and crashing the excel program. I've included _ Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal checkCell as Range) _ as the change event, and included this into Sheet 1 in the Macros

Comment: any errors when crashing?  from my last comment, that xlToRight is an issue and would send you to the end of the whole spreadsheet.  regarding "random" values, i would need more detail to understand what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

Small example to help you on your way...

```
dim lastcolumn as long, k as long
with sheets(1)
    lastcolumn = .cells(5,.columns.count).end(xltoleft).column
    if sheets(2).cells(1,1).value <> lastcolumn then k = sheets(2).cells(1,1).value - lastcolumn
    select case k
        case >0
            'insert columns
        case <0
            'remove columns
        case is 0
            'do nothing
    end select
end with
```

---

**Edit1:**

Corrected lastcolumn referencing .rows.count rather than .columns.count

Comment: This is great. I haven't ever used a Select Case statement before since I'm very new to vba, but this looks like a solid start. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting an error on line 3. It says "Application-defined or object-defined error". Do you know why this is?

Comment: @Andrew my bad; i had written rows.count, not columns.count... will update

Comment: Please take a look at my edit if you don't mind. I attempted to do it another way, but I am getting errors.